# How do I convert a Java object to JSON and vice versa using JMS message converters in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-jms, jackson-databind

What are the annotations required on the Java object? Which message converter should be used? A standalone Spring Boot application that converts a Java object into JSON and puts a message in the queue, and reads the JSON from the same queue as a Java object.

Comment: Here you go https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms/  Starter on how to do JMS with Jackson

Comment: Jackson is the JSON library recommended by Spring Boot: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial